# Mongoosejs object usage

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I connect to a `mongo DB` instance in my server.js file and import a model from another file.
My question is, how am I able to update the database with an object from a model which is not connected to a `mongoDB` instance in my `server.js` file ?
So I have a `server.js` which has the following lines:

```
//server.js
...
var mongoose   = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/Iganiq8o');
var Bear     = require('./app/models/bear');
var router = express.Router();  

router.route('/bears')

    .post(function(req, res) {

        var bear = new Bear(); 
        bear.name = req.body.name;

        bear.save(function(err) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);

            res.json({ message: 'Bear created!' });
        });

    });

app.use('/api', router);
...
```

And I have a model file like:

```
// app/models/bear.js
var mongoose     = require('mongoose');
var Schema       = mongoose.Schema;

var BearSchema   = new Schema({
    name: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Bear', BearSchema);
```

So, I am able to update the mongoDB using the Bear model, even though it never connects to a mongoDB instance in the bear.js file.

How does my bear (`var bear = new Bear();`) object know the `mongoDB` instance ? Any help as to how this happens ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the model was created via `mongoose.model`, the model is tied to the default connection pool created when you called `mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/Iganiq8o');`

This all works because calling `require('mongoose')` in any file returns the same, [cached](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_caching) instance of the Mongoose module.

Comment: Thanks. I searched the internet but could not find anything related to this. Could you point me to a resource where I could read about these intricacies of nodejs/mongoose ?